# Determine the matrix if we know eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have been doing one quite simple task and there is one thing that I do not understand.

I am aware of the following regarding eigenvectors: 
If A is an n×n matrix, the nonzero n-component column vector x is an eigenvector for eigenvalue λ if Ax=λx.

**Here is the exercise**: The matrix A has the eigenvalues −1 and 2 with corresponding eigenvectors
$\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$  and $\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Compute A.

**Now:** Let A be $$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b\\
    c & d\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
It follows that: [image: pic1]

***My question is:*** Given the statement at the top of this post should not the following apply instead?: 
$A \cdot \begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix}$ = $2 \cdot \begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Yes, it's a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a printing mistake. In particular, if $\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $2$, then:
$$
A\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = 2  \require{enclose}\enclose{updiagonalstrike,downdiagonalstrike}{\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}}  {\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}}
$$
by the definition of eigenvector. You can make the correction and proceed.